# node-gyp failed to rebuild @serialport/bindings

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

So I'm trying to rebuild this old Electron app and keep getting this error when running `electron-forge start`:

```
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\....\node_modules\@serialport\bindings'.
```

I've made sure to update all my electron packages and node-gyp, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference. I found a github issue for node-gyp that ended in saying this package called `johnny-five` was an issue, but I tried their fix and nothing changed.